# How to read the config.yaml file and feed it in snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I have a `ref.fasta` file that contains scaffolds. In order to parallelise the variant calling process I grouped scaffolds by chromosomes and created a `config.yaml` file as below:

```
samples:
    chr1A: scaffold26096,scaffold40476
    chr1B: scaffold11969,scaffold83281,scaffold43483
    chr1D: scaffold4701,scaffold102360
```

And a script as below.

```
configfile: "config.yaml"

rule all:
    input:
        expand("scaffolds/{sample}.vcf", sample=config["samples"])

rule gatk:
    input:
        "/path/to/ref.fasta",
        "/path/to/bam.list",
        lambda wildcards: config["samples"][wildcards.sample]
    output:
        outf ="scaffolds/{sample}.vcf"
    shell:
        """
        /Tools/gatk/gatk --java-options "-Xmx16g -XX:ParallelGCThreads=10" HaplotypeCaller -L {input[2]} -R {input[0]} -I {input[1]} -O {output.outf}
        """
```

I would like to get results as `chr1A.vcf`, `chr1B.vcf` and `chr1D.vcf`.

This is giving me an error:

```
Missing input files for rule gatk:
scaffold4701,scaffold102360
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think your yaml file does not contain the data you think it does. I guess you want each *chromosome* to contain a list of scaffolds, like:

```
samples: 
  chr1A: 
    - scaffold26096
    - scaffold40476
  chr1B: 
    - scaffold11969
    - scaffold83281
    - scaffold43483
  chr1D: 
    - scaffold4701
    - scaffold102360
```

(I haven't checked the rest of your code)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the config.yaml should be structured like this. It still gives me the same error.

Comment: So probably it is giving me errors because scaffolds are not files, by sequence names in the ref.fasta file?